# iFrame vs XFBML

Tags: facebook, iframe, xfbml

I'm getting a bit confused by these two operations. Before I wrote this question, I looked at 5 or 6 other articles concerning the two but, I still couldn't get a clear solution to what I need to know.

Am I correct in saying that the use of 'iFrame' in codes is NOT compatible with a LOT of mobile devices? I've always seen XFBML is more appropriate. I even tried it on some of my mobile devices and had some "mixed" results. Can someone please set me on the 'right' course of code?

Comment: It's not IFRAME vs XFBML - you use them both together. it's FBML + FBJS vs IFRAME + XFBML + JS api

Answer (score 0):

use xFBML only when you are sure that you need a particular function provided by xFBML, e.g. multi-friend-selector.

Otherwise, iframe is always the choice now.

Comment: XFBML works on iframe just fine, I think you're confusing FBML vs. XFBML

Comment: My Android device doesn't seem to like iFrame (EVO 4G), and won't display it at times.